# Cython in Pure Python Mode with python class within C code

Tags: python, cython

From Cython [documentation](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/pure.html), it is possible to compile a pure python script as a C library using extending `.pxd`.

But I am not able to use the example as it is. My final goal is to call function and class from the python module directly as C object (meaning not using a python session within C program).

Files are:

- foo.py: the python module
- foo.pxd: the associated header file for cython compiler
- main.c: the C program in which I need to use the python object

foo.py

```
from __future__ import print_function

def myfunction(x, y=2):
    a = x - y
    res = a + x * y
    print("myfunction:result is:", res)
    return res

def _helper(a):
    res = a + 1
    print("_helper:result is:", res)
    return res

class A:
    def __init__(self, b=0):
        self.a = 3
        self.b = b

    def foo(self, x):
        print(x + _helper(1.0))
```

foo.pxd

```
cpdef int myfunction(int x, int y=*)
cdef double _helper(double a)

cdef class A:
    cdef public int a, b
    cpdef foo(self, double x)
```

main.c

```
#include <Python.h> //needed
#include <foo.h>

int main(void){
    Py_Initialize();  //Needed!
    initfoo();      //Needed! called PyInit_hello() for Python3
    _helper(3.);
    myfunction(3,2);
    A a;
    a.foo(3.);
    Py_Finalize();    //Needed!
}
```

Makefile

```
CC     := gcc
# CFLAGS := $(shell python-config --cflags) -c -fPIC -g -ggdb -O0 -D_DEBUG
CFLAGS := -c -fPIC -g -ggdb -O0 -D_DEBUG -Wall #-Werror
LDFLAGS:= -shared
# CLIBS  := -L$(shell python-config --prefix)/lib $(shell python-config --ldflags)
CLIBS  := -L/usr/local/python-gnu-2.7.8/lib -lpython2.7
RM     := rm -f
CYTHON := cython

INCLUDE_PATH := -I/usr/local/python-gnu-2.7.8/include/python2.7

.PHONY: all clean

NAME := main
CYTHONSRC := foo.py
CYTHONOBJS := $(CYTHONSRC:.py=.so)
LIBS := libfoo.so
SRCS := #main.c # $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)

all: $(NAME)

lib: $(LIBS)

#
libfoo.so: foo.o
    $(CC) -I. -L. $(LDFLAGS) $(CLIBS) -o $@ $^
#
# link the .o files into the target executable
#
$(NAME): $(LIBS) $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CLIBS) $(INCLUDE_PATH) $(CFLAGS) -I. -L. -lfoo -o $@ $@.c
#
# compile the .c file into .o files using the compiler flags
#
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATH) -I. $<

%.c: %.py
    python -m cython $<
    # $(CYTHON) -o $@ $<

clean:
    $(RM) $(CYTHONSRC:.py=.c)
    $(RM) $(CYTHONSRC:.py=.h)
    $(RM) $(CYTHONSRC:.py=.o)
    $(RM) $(LIBS)
    $(RM) main
```

**EDIT**:
But make gives this errors:

```
main.c:10:5: error: unknown type name 'A'
     A a;
     ^
main.c:11:6: error: request for member 'foo' in something not a structure or union
     a.foo(3.);
      ^
```

Comment: The errors you are shown don't match with the `main.cpp`: there is no `a.foo(3)`  in the main.cpp

Comment: I would not recommend `.py`-ending for a Cython-file but `.pyx`. Having a py-file with the same name as your module around could confuse the python interpreter in some scenarios.

Comment: Ok, my bad for the errors shown. I forgot to modify the main.c file. It is fixed now.

Comment: Did you look into the produced foo.h? Is there a `struct A` defined? I guess not. Also you cannot have functions as members of a struct in C. That is just too much to ask.

Comment: In fact, no struct A in the headers... it was the implicit part of my question. The only point I don't understand is that I took this small example straight from the cython documentation. Why do they write a such class if you cannot use it ?

Comment: Those classes are for consuming from Python/Cython and not from C. The documentation you have linked to are for usage in Python/Cython. C dosn't know classes, there is no way Cython could define classes in C for you. You however could use the functionality of these classes via Python-API from C, which is slightly less straight forward than what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok thanks. I open another question for the function-only part https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558131/use-of-cython-pure-python-mode-in-c